# looping inside stored procedures

Tags: sql, triggers, db2

I am writing a trigger in DB2. Inside that i wanted to use a loop.
This is to iterate through a set of values returned from a select statement.
How can this be done?
Anybody please share a tutorial or link which explains this.
Also is it ok to have nested loop?

Comment: Why are you looping?  Is it possible to change your statement to work on a _set_?  A further explanation of your need may help in that regard; looping in SQL almost (but not) always runs counter to the proper use or conventions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cursor in your trigger:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_%28databases%29

A simple cursor example looks like this:

```
DECLARE SQLSTATE CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000';
DECLARE p_sum INTEGER;
SET p_sum = 0;
DECLARE p_sal INTEGER;

DECLARE c CURSOR FOR SELECT SALARY FROM EMPLOYEE;
OPEN c;

FETCH FROM c INTO p_sal;

WHILE(SQLSTATE = '00000') DO
   SET p_sum = p_sum + p_sal;
   FETCH FROM c INTO p_sal; 
END WHILE;

CLOSE c;
```

Comment: Referring the OP to a [DB2-specific documentation page about cursors](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/topic/com.ibm.db2.udb.apdv.sql.doc/doc/c0024361.htm) might be more helpful then suggesting a generic article on the topic (and all the more so since the example seems to be taken from the former).